# Cannot Video Capture With opencv on macOS

Tags: python, opencv

On python when I try to video capture with open cv2 I get that :

```
2021-11-18 11:07:36.572 Python[5863:20765] =>> Checked Property: [cfen] 1667655022
2021-11-18 11:07:36.572 Python[5863:20765] =>> Checked Property: [cfen] 1667655022
2021-11-18 11:07:36.572 Python[5863:20765] =>> Checked Property: [cfen] 1667655022
2021-11-18 11:07:36.572 Python[5863:20765] =>> Checked Property: [cfac] 1667653987
2021-11-18 11:07:36.621 Python[5863:20765] =>> Checked Property: [cfen] 1667655022
2021-11-18 11:07:36.622 Python[5863:20765] =>> Checked Property: [cfen] 1667655022
2021-11-18 11:07:36.722 Python[5863:20765] =>> Checked Property: [cfen] 1667655022
2021-11-18 11:07:36.722 Python[5863:20765] =>> Checked Property: [cfen] 1667655022
```

i also this windows opening :

[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wowGk.png)

this is my code :

```
    
    import cv2


    trained_face_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
 
  
    webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
    
    ret, frame = webcam.read()
   
   
    grayscaled_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    cv2.imshow('image face detector', grayscaled_img)
    
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved just have to change the parameters  `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`to `cv2.VideoCapture(2)`

hope that can helps other Mac users